# Proof problem : show that $\frac{n_{1}n_{2}-1}{2}$ = $\frac{n_{1}-1}{2}$ + $\frac{n_{2}-1}{2}$ mod(2)

Tags: legendre-symbol

I want to show that, for odd positive integers $n_{1}$ and $n_{2}$, we have :

$\frac{n_{1}n_{2}-1}{2}$ = $\frac{n_{1}-1}{2}$ + $\frac{n_{2}-1}{2}$  mod(2)

Let $n_{1}$ = ${2m_{1} +1}$ and $n_{2}$ = ${2m_{2} +1}$

I get :

2${m_{1}m_{2}} + {m_{1}} + {m_{2}}$  $\cong$  ${m_{1} + m_{2}}$ mod(2)

My question is : how this is proving the statement ? I am not sure what to do next.

Comment: $n_2n_2 - 1 \equiv (n_1 - 1)(n_2 - 1) + n_1 + n_2 - 2 \equiv (n_1 - 1) + (n_2 - 1)\pmod{4}$.

Comment: What has this to do with primality testing?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos you're right, I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can drop the $2m_1m_2$ since working mod $2.$

Comment: Thank you! How could I deduce from that that (-1/n) = (-1)^((n-1)/2) ?

Comment: @ miskinalien Am I right in interpreting $(-1/a)$ as the quadratic residue symbol? [That is, it is $+1$ if $-1$ is a residue mod $a$ and $-1$ if $-1$ is a nonresidue mod $a$]

Comment: If your $(-1/n)$ is meant as suggested in my last comment, note that the formula of your comment requires (in general) that $n$ be an odd prime, not just any odd positive integer. For example $(-1)^{((9-1)/2)}=+1$ would if true  suggest that $-1=8$ is a residue mod $9$, but the residues mod $9$ are $0,1,4,7$ making $8$ a *nonresidue* in this case. But using non-primes as "denominators" in $(a/n)$ requires special care, look up Jacobi symbol.